# General Settings: display custom plugin field after Site Address field

Tags: jquery, settings-api

For my custom settings field, I am looking to insert it [right after the *Site Address (URL)* field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cds8f.png) in the *General* settings page.

I'm able to add the custom field sucessfully using the `add_settings_field()`. Be default, it add the custom field [at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYryA.png). Using jQuery, I was able to display my custom field after the *Site Address (URL)*:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'wpse_243810_admin_footer' );
function wpse_243810_admin_footer() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#protocol_relative').closest('tr').insertAfter('#home-description').closest('tr');
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

However, it looks like the following instead:

[image]

Looking at the code, it inserts my custom field within the Site Address field's `<tr>` element. How get I have it inserted outide of it instead? Below are the seperate code snippets of each field.

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><label for="home">Site Address (URL)</label></th>
    <td>
        <input name="home" type="url" id="home" aria-describedby="home-description" value="http://example.com" class="regular-text code">
        <p class="description" id="home-description">Enter the address here if you <a href="//codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory">want your site home page to be different from your WordPress installation directory.</a></p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the custom field that my plugin generates which I want ot insert after:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Protocol Relative URL</th>
    <td>
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="screen-reader-text"><span>Protocol Relative URL</span></legend>
            <label for="remove_http">
            <input name="protocol_relative" type="checkbox" id="protocol_relative" value="1" checked="checked">Do not apply to external links
            </label>
            <p class="description">Only the internal links will be affected.</p>
        </fieldset>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by using the following jQuery function. The `#protocol_relative` is the field I am inserting and `#home-description` is the field I am inserting it after:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'insert_field' );
function insert_field() {
    # Insert the settings field after the 'Site Address (URL)'
    ?> <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( '#protocol_relative' ).closest( 'tr' ).insertAfter( jQuery( '#home-description' ).closest( 'tr' ) );
    </script> <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is not possible without modifying the core-files. We only have one time `do_settings_fields` and `do_settings_sections` in the options-permalink.php between line 226 and 232 for the `optional` section.

```
...
    </tr>
    <?php do_settings_fields('permalink', 'optional'); ?>
</table>

<?php do_settings_sections('permalink'); ?>

<?php submit_button(); ?>
...
```

The WordPress functions `add_settings_field` and `add_settings_section` are using the [settings api](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API). In the core files are the `do_settings_fields` and `do_settings_sections` functions which will add custom fields or sections (which u added with this api). These are required to place anything in a page. Also these functions are only placed (hardcoded) in the options section of the permalink page. You dont have an access-point in the geneal section like for the options section.

Answer (score 0):

You might just be missing the [`add_settings_section`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section) before [`add_settings_field`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field). This works, and saves the field to an [`option`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option), but I might button up that portion. I just wanted to hook earlier than the checks in [`options-permalink.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/options-permalink.php).

```
<?php

// ADD SETTINGS

add_action('admin_head', function(){

    // Create a section after the permalink

    add_settings_section(
        'permalink_relative_setting_section_options',           // id
        __( 'Protocol Relative URL', 'textdomain' ),            // title
        'premalink_relative_setting_section_callback_function', // callback
        'permalink'                                             // page
    );

    // Add a field to the section

    add_settings_field(
        'permalink_relative_settings_field-id',          // id
        '',                                              // title
        'permalink_relative_settings_field_callback',    // callback
        'permalink',                                     // page
        'permalink_relative_setting_section_options',    // section
        array( 'some_arg' => 'For use in the callback' ) // args
    );

});

// SECTION

function premalink_relative_setting_section_callback_function( $args ) {

    // Echo SECTION intro text here

    /*
    echo '<p>id: ' . esc_html( $args['id'] ) . '</p>';                         // id: eg_setting_section
    echo '<p>title: ' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $args['title'] ) . '</p>'; // title: Example settings section in reading
    echo '<p>callback: ' . esc_html( $args['callback'] ) . '</p>';             // callback: eg_setting_section_callback_function
    */
}

// FIELD

function permalink_relative_settings_field_callback( $args ) {

    $options = get_option( 'permalink_relative_setting_section_options' );

    $html = '<input type="checkbox" id="relative_checkbox" name="permalink_relative_setting_section_options[relative_checkbox]" value="1"' . checked( 1, $options[ 'relative_checkbox' ], false ) . '/>';

    $html .= '<label for="relative_checkbox">Do not apply to external links</label>';

    echo $html;
}

// UPDATE

add_action( 'init', function() {

    // If permalink structure is detected, let's update our option before the page can act

    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'permalink_structure' ] ) || isset( $_POST[ 'category_base' ] ) ) {

        check_admin_referer( 'update-permalink' );

        $options = get_option( 'permalink_relative_setting_section_options' );

        $options[ 'relative_checkbox' ] = ( isset( $_POST[ 'permalink_relative_setting_section_options' ][ 'relative_checkbox' ] ) && $_POST[ 'permalink_relative_setting_section_options' ][ 'relative_checkbox' ] === '1' )
            ? '1' // checked
            : '';

        update_option( 'permalink_relative_setting_section_options', $options );
    }
} );
```

### Alternate

If you look at https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/options-permalink.php#L178 there aren't any hooks to do what you want you want.

Consider jQuery's [manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) methods like [`detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) and [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) which you could utilize in the [`admin_footer`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_footer).

```
jQuery('<h1>Protocol Relative URL Form!</h1>').insertAfter('.form-table.permalink-structure');
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it a go. Unfortunately, after playing around with your code,  it still adds a section to the bottom of the permalinks page, rather than a custom field after the _Common Settings_ section. I've update my question with another alternative that I'm willing to take.

Comment: Sorry about that. I must have glossed over where you wanted it. Have you considered jQuery in the `admin_footer` to move it exactly where you want? That could save you a lot of effort in the long run.

Comment: I was thinking about that after I updated my option. Honestly, the end result is what matters, I'm open to whatever option is needed to achieve that goal.

Comment: Well, by `admin_footer`, I think I just mean enqueue scripts or inline them in the footer to trigger the form field shuffle after the page loads.